# sending pointer from unique_ptr::get into function as pointer reference

Tags: c++

Ok so i have a unique pointer and use the unique_ptr::get to get the pointer and pass that into say a std::function that has the params of `int*& b`. It seems to be returning a error. Im just curious as to what i did wrong and how to fix it. I've put a little code snippet bellow thanks.

```cpp
std::function<void(int*& b)> foo;

int main()
{
    foo = [&](int*& b) {
        b++;
    };
    std::unique_ptr<int> i = std::make_unique<int>(5);
    foo(i.get());
}
```

Comment: Note that incrementing a pointer that is not pointing to an array element has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @George You can increment pointer to any object outside of array once, and the result will be an "out of bounds" pointer as if the object had been in an array of size one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unique_ptr::get()` returns a pointer `int*`, not a reference to a pointer `int*&`. This is because you should not be able to change the pointer stored in the `unique_ptr` from the outside. The returned pointer is a temporary (rvalue) and this cannot be bound to a non-const reference, only to a const reference.

In your case as your function really needs to change the pointer you need to first store the pointer in a variable (lvalue), which then can be passed to the function by non-const reference.

```
int *p{ i.get() };
foo(p);
```

Comment: ok thank you for the explanation as well as the functional code. I'll accept ur answer when it lets me and thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: @Jacob I just saw that you really need to change the pointer, so I stripped down my answer to only what is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Lvalue reference to non-const cannot be bound to an rvalue. It can be bound to an lvalue however:

```
int* ptr = i.get();
foo(ptr);
```

Comment: I think you mean `int * ptr`, not `int ptr`.

Comment: @WernerHenze Indeed. Fixed